# NopCommerce: How do I map this gateway's returned fields to what Nop is expecting?

Tags: c#, e-commerce, payment-gateway, nopcommerce

**BACKGROUND**

I am writing a payment gateway plugin for [NopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx) 2.80. This is my first time writing code for a payment gateway. I am almost there, but having a few problems.

**PROBLEMS**

- Firstly, in the `ProcessPayment` method, I need to return a `ProcessPaymentResult`, which has the following properties (Can someone please explain to me the difference between these?):

`AuthorizationTransactionCode`

`AuthorizationTransactionId`

`AuthorizationTransactionResult`

`CaptureTransactionId`

`CaptureTransactionResult`

The gateway I need to implement (Tranzila) has the following fields returned:

`ConfirmationCode`

`AuthNumber`

`RefNumber`

`TempRef`

and a few others which probably don't apply in this scenario. I don't know how to map these to what Nop is expecting...

- Secondly, what is the `Capture` method for? I've looked at the `PayPalDirect` plugin, but it's not very clear. When is this method called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fields are saved into the order after verifying that if `processPaymentResult.Success` is true. All of them are optional but you need to include them if you want to have some kind of reference between orders in nopcommerce and payment transactions in Tranzila.

- `AuthorizationTransactionId` (optional) is a unique id genereated by you if you want to record the transaction
- `AuthorizationTransactionCode` is the unique transaction Id generated by the payment gateway. In your case it might be `RefNumber`. But I would double-check.
- `AuthorizationTransactionResult` is the whole response returned by the payment gateway. You could save just text or the whole XML response. This is again, just for future references.

The other 2 fields are used in deferred payments. They are set when the 'admin' captures the money from the admin panel.

- `CaptureTransactionId` transaction code generated by the payment gateway
- `CaptureTransactionResult` the whole message of that transaction